# Spring: How to start the logic after initializing the app

Tags: java, spring

I have implemented this logic

```
@Component
public class SomeUpdater {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher;
    private ExecutorService executorService;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        executorService.execute(()->{
            //some logic
            applicationEventPublisher.publishEvent(new PurposeEvent(this, 5));
        });
    }

}

@Component
public class SomeClass {

    @EventListener
    public void update(PurposeEvent purposeEvent){
        //update
    }
}
```

But I can see from the logs that listener for `update (PurposeEvent purposeEvent)` is initialized later than the method `applicationEventPublisher.publishEvent(new PurposeEvent(this, 5));` is called. How can I call logic after initialization? I tried using `@EventListener` for `ContextRefreshedEvent`, but as far as I understand, it can be called multiple times

Answer (score 0):

You can you annotation @DependsOn which can force the Spring container to initialize one or more beans before the bean annotated with @DependsOn annotation.
Then you'll be sure that SomeClass will be initialized before SomeUpdater.

The long term solution would be:

1. Spring Boot startup hooks
2. Spring Event types, like ApplicationStartedEvent, ApplicationReadyEvent.

Useful links:
http://dolszewski.com/spring/running-code-on-spring-boot-startup/
http://javainfinite.com/spring-boot/springboot-applicationreadyevent-applicationfailedevent-contextrefreshedevent/

Comment: Thank you. But I use Spring and some tips are not for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of spring events like below,

```
@EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
public void init() {
    final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    executorService.execute(() -> {
        //some logic
        applicationEventPublisher.publishEvent(new PurposeEvent(this, 5));
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think this event is for Spring Boot. I use Spring